# Websites from the same hosting doesn't open only from my router/proovider

Tags: hosting, timeout, connection-refused, accessibility

Faced with a strange problem.

I have a hosting with few websites. Starting from today I can't navigate any of them from any device, connected to home wifi. But I can ping each domain.

Chrome fails with Timeout, while mobile browser fails with Connection Refused.

And there are nobody (as far as I know) who experiencing the same problem.

The only changes were made during this period are (for domain config):

```
1. added TXT domain_key record
2. added TXT @ SPF record
```

Tried to restart router, get a new IP, flush DNS, restart hosting.

**UPD.**

nslookup shows:

```
nslookup domain.com
Server: unknown
Address: 192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: domain.com
Address: <correct IP>
```

tracert domain.com

```
output doesn't show any errors and show trace without any problems tight to the domain.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my box there was installed iRedMail bundle with fail2ban.

By some reason fail2ban banned my ip automatically.

to watch all banned items execute:

```
fail2ban-client -S
```

To unban IP from iRedMail postfix list:

```
fail2ban-client set postfix-iredmail unbanip <ip>
```

where *postfix_iredmail* is fail2ban JAIL name (the list of all jails can be retrieved by status command).